# Expression Engine has hit the ten year mark!

Tags: discussion

We recently announced that our Stack Exchange community was turning a decade old. We’re so excited to celebrate this milestone together. This is a shared effort by our dedicated community of contributors, curators, and moderators. A blog post featuring our site and the other communities who are also turning 10 this quarter will be going live in the next few weeks.

The moderators of the Stack Exchange site wanted to take this opportunity to say thank you. Over the past decade our community has provided the world with over 12K questions and 16K answers related to Expression Engine. We look forward to seeing the contributions that will come in during this next decade. Happy anniversary to us all!